# How use `if` and `for` in the same line of code?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

please look at the following code:

```
for l in range(len(cosine_scores)):
            for s in range(len(skill_index)):
                if l!=skill_index[s] :
                    if cosine_scores[l][skill_index[s]]>=0.80:
                        print(l)
```

How I can rewrite this code in the way that if condition satisfy for all `s` before printing `l`?

For example if I have

```
my_list=[[10,8],[8,,0,1,2,7],[6,15,8]]

for i in my_list:
    for j in i:
       if j>5:      # I don't know what I should add here to say if this condition is true for all j in i. 
         print(i)
```

The correct out put should be `[10,8]` and `[6,15,8]`.

Comment: What do you mean by "condition satisfy for all s before printing l"? Try describing this very precisely in words without worrying about python syntax. Do you want every element of `skill_index` to be equal to the current element of `cosine_curves`?

Comment: For your second example, check out the `all()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### General case

1. #### `all` method

   The [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)
   *Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty)*

   ```
   for i in my_list:
       if all(j > 5 for j in i):
           print(i)
   ```
2. #### `for/else`

   The `else` block is called only of no `break` has been used during the iteration

   ```
   for i in my_list:
       for j in i:
           if not j > 5:
               break
       else:
           print(i)
   ```

---

### Your case

```
for l in range(len(cosine_scores)):
    for s in range(len(skill_index)):
        if not (l != skill_index[s] and cosine_scores[l][skill_index[s]] >= 0.80):
            break
    else:
        print(l)

--- 

for l in range(len(cosine_scores)):
    if all(l != skill and cosine_scores[l][skill] >= 0.80 for skill in skill_index):
        print(l)
```

Comment: An alternative option, if your check is small, and your list is big, that may be faster is reverse this. have a "bad list" like `bad=[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and then use `if any(x in good for x in bad): check=False` and then `if check: print(good)`  --- i'm not saying this is ideal, but sometimes working it backwards can save a ton of time. especially when your "bad" list is relatively smaller  - You could also just do `if any(x in good for x in range(0,6)`  -- to put it differently, this is looping through the smaller list instead of the larger list (which could be 10k lines in some situations)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a boolean variable as switch:

```py
my_list=[[10,8],[8,,0,1,2,7],[6,15,8]]

for i in my_list:
    
    ALLTRUE = True

    for j in i:
        if not j>5:
            ALLTRUE = False
    
    if ALLTRUE:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner solution using [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
result = [i for i in my_list if all(j > 5 for j in i)]
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually solve problems like this with a boolean.

```
my_list=[[10,8],[8,0,1,2,7],[6,15,8]]

printIt = True

for i in my_list:
    for j in i:
        if j<5:   
            printIt = False
    if printIt:
        print(i)
    else:
        printIt = True
```